# How to prevent PHP MySQL-query multiple insert due to .htaccess?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

To send users to the correct page on my website, I use mod_rewrite in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*) thirdpage.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ secondpage.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ firstpage.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works fine.

In my php-file I save the http_referer's:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
mysqli_query($con,"insert into refs set id=NULL, refurl='".$url."', date=NOW()");
```

Works fine too, but in the db-table this one query creates between 5 and 17 identical lines, depending on what page is loaded. The user_agent doesn't make a difference: bots and humans all create the same amount of lines.

Though the mysqli_query is run just once in the code, it seems it's been called for multiple times. I've already ruled out the images and the directories by adding to the .htaccess these lines:

```
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*) css/$1 [L]
```

This didn't solve the problem.
If I don't use .htaccess, just one line is inserted.

Is there something I have to add or remove from the .htaccess-file to solve this?

Comment: The HTTP Referer can be spoofed by the client. This means you are vulnerable to SQL Injection. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, that will be the next step. But doesn't answer my question. :-)

Comment: What information is written to Apache access log?